# What algorithm is used in this animation from Yojouhan Shinwa Taikei?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graphics, rectangles

Is there a name for the type of effect where rectangular shapes are increased/decreased in size relational to each other? I'm looking for a general algorithm, formula, diagram, etc so I can re-create it in d3.js. Here it is (originally made in After Effects I think):

[image: Yojouhan Shinwa Taikei Ending]

Source: [The Tatami Galaxy (Yojouhan Shinwa Taikei / 四畳半神話大系) - Clear END](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ewICfFjc4CI)

I've looked into [voronoi diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) but I see no way to create rectangular shapes instead of regular polygons.

Comment: At least half of those shapes are not actually rectangles. I don't know the algorithm but it looks like it is specified by just a bunch of parallel lines and at each crossing you decide which line wins and goes on and which stops at this intersection. This gives you the initial picture. Then you  just move some lines randomly preserving the crossing logic. Also you can add a logic that sometimes at the crossing both lines "survive" but then one of them can be split in to at next movement.

Comment: @SergGr I've edited my post to mention i'm looking for **rectangular** shapes, not actual rectangles. I'll look into trying to implement what you suggested though, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's looks similar to a 2d tree-mapping Algorithm and it's an optimization problem (operation research).

Comment: I searched up 2d tree-mapping and this looks very close thanks! Question though, what do you mean by "optimization problem (operation research)"?

Comment: @Sosa mathematical problem